# Spacy IS_ALPHA matcher-pattern not working?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Regarding the following setup:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
from spacy.attrs import POS, LOWER, IS_ALPHA

nlp_en = spacy.load('en')

text = nlp_en('A nice looking great blue house you have!')

matcher = Matcher(text.vocab)

OP = 'OP'

matcher.add_entity('test')
matcher.add_pattern('test', [
    {LOWER: 'nice'},
    {OP: '*', IS_ALPHA: True},
    {LOWER: 'house'}
    ])

matches = matcher(text)
```

I am trying to find any word between `nice` and `house` in this case - but the matcher won´t yield any result. Also I tried flipping `{OP: '*', IS_ALPHA: True}` to `{IS_ALPHA: True, OP: '*'}` but also no results. What is wrong with this pattern?

Spacy Version: 1.9.0

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting a bug in the matcher here, unfortunately. The operators aren't implemented correctly.

What's happening is the variable-length operator '*' is matching the end token 'house', preventing 'house' from ever matching.

The bug occurs whenever you have a variable-length operator that overlaps with the next part of the pattern.

If you have time and inclination I'd love a pull request on this, but admittedly the matcher code is very difficult. It should probably be reimplemented entirely.

Comment: Is there a work around? Something like 'anything but no `NOUN`'. I would love to help but my coding-skills are too low I guess

Comment: This seems to be working in more recent versions of spacy. I am using 2.3.5. Some of the method names have changed, so the OP's code would need to be adjusted.